# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-connection, ssms

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 express edition from SQL Server Management.

From the server configuration manager, I found the SQL Server Service to be running and within bracket, it's written(SQLEXPRESS). I understand SQLEXPRESS is the instance name, therefore I have to use following string for server name: \SQLEXPRESS.

I am using windows authentication. I am logged into an account that is non admin.

Can someone suggest me how I can establish the connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.\SQLEXPRESS`..

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> By default, SQL Server Express
>   installs as an instance named
>   "SQLEXPRESS," for example. You connect
>   to a named instance by specifying the
>   instance name with the server name in
>   the connection string. That is why you
>   normally specify ".\SQLEXPRESS" as the
>   server name when connecting to a local
>   SQL Server Express database. The dot
>   means the local server and \SQLEXPRESS
>   specifies the SQLEXPRESS named
>   instance.

Comment: do you mean IP.\SQLEXPRESS or just .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Cool, it worked with .\SQLEXPRESS. Just want to know, why it didn't work with IP?

Comment: `.` just means 'it's on the local server'.  If you want to use IP address I imagine it would involve `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` somehow.

Comment: What about directly using my IP address as registered in the system?

Comment: SQL Server defaults to TCP/IP so using the '.' as you are now doing already does this.  See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191260.aspx.  Are you talking now about connecting from another remote system?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know why can't I use my machines IP instead. I think, that may require additional parameters being defined. But what you have mentioned solves the specific problem I have at hand.